# Is there a style check tool for T-SQL, just like FxCop to .net?

Tags: sql, coding-style

I'm looking for a tool to enforce coding styles, validation check for T-SQL script. And it recommends best-practice when appliable.

In .net code domain, the tool for this purpose is FxCop. Is there a counterpart for T-SQL? It will be best it is free or open source tool.

Anyone can shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DA3F11AD-BD54-4EDA-B08C-4DF84DF0D641&displaylang=en) is your best bet.

Also, here is a Microsoft tool for verifying best practices.  The documentation specifies it checks T-SQL.  It may or may not do what you want.

[2000](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B352EB1F-D3CA-44EE-893E-9E07339C1F22&displaylang=en)

[2005](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DA0531E4-E94C-4991-82FA-F0E3FBD05E63&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at the RedGate suite of tools, particularly SQL Refactor and SQL Prompt.

This will layout your T-SQL code in a standard fashion and also provide you the ability to customise the standards that are used for your specific shop.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm

Cheers, John